# string edit distance algorithm confusion

Tags: algorithm, edit-distance

Here are the edit distance definition. My question is whether edit distance from word 1 to word 2, is always the same as edit distance from word 2 to word 1, and why? Thanks.

Given two words word1 and word2, edit distance is the minimum number of steps required to convert word1 to word2.
(each operation is counted as 1 step.)

There are 3 operations permitted on a word:

a) Insert a character
b) Delete a character
c) Replace a character

regards,
Lin

Comment: In general, it depends on which edit distance algorithm you're talking about.

Comment: @hatchet, thanks for the reply and vote up. My question might be confusing, actually I do not mean a specific edit distance algorithm implementation, I mean edit distance result from the algorithms. If you have any advice, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always the same: the process to come from w1 to w2 can be run backwards in the same number of steps.

For each step a) there is a corresponding step b) and vice versa. Each step c) can be undone by another step c).

Comment: Thanks Henry, vote up, suppose you found the optimal steps from w1 to w2, but how do you know if running backwards the correspond steps is most optimal (i.e. minimal number of steps) from w2 to w1?

Comment: If it wasn't optimal (i.e. there is a shorter sequence) you could reverse this and construct a shorter sequence from w1 to w2. This contradicts the optimality of the original sequence from w1 to w2.

Comment: Thanks Henry, this is smart and vote up. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both ways will cost the same no of steps. Because in your optimal solution to convert `word1` to `word2` lets suppose if you are adding a character then eventually in your optimal solution to convert `word2` to `word1` you would be deleting a character. So when you give same cost to these deletion and addition operations , the cost will always be same whether you convert `word1` to `word2` or vice-versa.

Comment: But are insertion and deletion costs supposed to always be equal? Isn't it possible to change them?

Comment: @KurtBourbaki they can be different, though in that case both the solutions can be different.